# Address Settings missing

Tags: addresses, settings

Not sure what happened. The image below shows a blank page when I open Address Settings from the Localization menu.

[image: Snip from site]

Comment: Try clearing CiviCRM cache. Administer > System Settings > Cleanup Caches and Update Paths.

Comment: Thanks @Anil, tried that but no difference.

Comment: Does this also happen with other Localization options or just Address?

Comment: Is everything else working - or is this one of many symptoms?

Comment: The only place this shows up is in Addresses, there are other symptoms. I'm thinking about removing CiviCRM and reinstalling, any other suggestions on how to clean up the database?

Answer (score 1):

Seems to have been related to an extension, when I removed the extension I was able to get everything working again.

Comment: Was this an official extension and if so, could you name it for the community?

Comment: Summary Fields, seems to have mangled part of the database dealing with addresses. Afraid I'm not quite knowledgeable enough to say more than that.

Comment: Not sure if this is related, but I'm seeing this in my logs: '[info] $backTrace = #0 /var/www/html/sites/all/modules/civicrm/CRM/Core/Error.php(232): CRM_Core_Error::backtrace("backTrace", TRUE)
#1 /var/www/html/sites/all/modules/civicrm/packages/PEAR.php(921): CRM_Core_Error::handle(Object(DB_Error))
#2 /var/www/html/sites/all/modules/civicrm/packages/DB.php(985): PEAR_Error->__construct("DB Error: unknown error", -1, 16, (Array:2), "SELECT contact_a.id as contact_id, contact_a.contact_type as `contact_type`, ...")'